# How to change version code in AndroidManifest.xml using Cordova 3.6.4

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

I am trying to change the version code in `AndroidManifest.xml.` I am using **Cordova 3.6.4.**

As per the docs I am updating it in the **config.xml** but it is not reflecting in the **AndroidManifest.xml** after the build.

**Config.xml**

```
<widget id="" versionCode="6" version="2.0.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

**AndroidManifest.xml after build**

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="20002" android:versionName="2.0.2" package="" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per [Cordova API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html) docs:

Both, **Android** and **iOS** support a **second version string** (or **number**) in addition to the one visible in app stores, **versionCode** for Android and **CFBundleVersion** for iOS.

Below is an example that explicitly sets versionCode and CFBundleVersion

```
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova"
  version="0.0.1"
  android-versionCode="7"
  ios-CFBundleVersion="3.3.3">
```

If **alternative** version is not specified, the following defaults will be used:

```
// assuming version = MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH-whatever
versionCode = PATCH + MINOR * 100 + MAJOR * 10000
CFBundleVersion = "MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH"
```

Comment: @AAhad I'm running into the same issue. I pasted my widget tag. But for some reason the android version code is using the alternate not specified calculation. Any suggestions?

<widget id="org.app.app" version="0.1.4" android-versionCode="13" ios-CFBundleVersion="3.3.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">

Comment: @AAhad
I actually figured out the issue

If your application has enabled the cdvBuildMultipleApks Gradle property (see Setting Gradle Properties), the version code of your app will also be multiplied by 10 so that the last digit of the code can be used to indicate the architecture the apk was built for. This multiplication will happen regardless of whether the version code is taken from the android-versionCode attribute or generated using the version. Be aware that some plugins added to your project (including cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) may set this Gradle property automatically.

Comment: For those who would like the Ionic Documentation regarding my comments
[https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#setting-the-version-code](Cordova Setting the Version Code in config.xml).